ValueError: {"detail":"Not Found"} while connecting to chromaDB
I am encountering an issue when using chromadb version 0.5.20, where it raises a ValueError: {"detail":"Not Found"} error. However, this issue does not occur with chromadb version 0.5.3, which works perfectly.
This is the function I have used to connect the database and store the collection in cache.
def client_formation():
    """
    Function to get and calling the data fetching function.
    :return: Returning the all source documents.
    """

    if os.environ['ENVIRONMENT'] == "dev":

        collections = collection
        return_cache = cache
    else:
        collections = vector_collections
        return_cache = documents_cache

    for collect in collections:
        client_key = list(collect.keys())[0]
        client_data = collect[client_key]
        client_config = vector_db_config(client_data['tenant'], client_data['database'])

        if client_data['collect_1']:
            get_documents_from_vectorstore(client_config, client_data['collect_1'], client_data['cache_key_1'])
        if client_data['collect_2']:
            get_documents_from_vectorstore(client_config, client_data['collect_2'], client_data['cache_key_2'])

    return return_cache

The error was
INFO:chromadb.telemetry.product.posthog:Anonymized telemetry enabled. See                     https://docs.trychroma.com/telemetry for more information.
INFO:httpx:HTTP Request: GET https://develop/api/v2/auth/identity "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/power/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/api/base_http_client.py", line 99, in _raise_chroma_error
    resp.raise_for_status()
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/power/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpx/_models.py", line 763, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPStatusError(message, request=request, response=self)
httpx.HTTPStatusError: Client error '404 Not Found' for url 'https://develop/api/v2/auth/identity'
For more information check: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/power/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/api/client.py", line 101, in get_user_identity
    return self._server.get_user_identity()
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/power/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/telemetry/opentelemetry/__init__.py", line 150, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/power/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/api/fastapi.py", line 144, in get_user_identity
    return UserIdentity(**self._make_request("get", "/auth/identity"))
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/power/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/api/fastapi.py", line 90, in _make_request
    BaseHTTPClient._raise_chroma_error(response)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/power/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/api/base_http_client.py", line 104, in _raise_chroma_error
    raise (Exception(resp.text))
Exception: {"detail":"Not Found"}

Share your thoughts and solutions about this issue, thanks in advance.
I want to use the updated chromaDB version.
